# Corrupted jar file

Tags: java, file, jar, manifest

I "converted" the jar file into a zip folder
and then to a normal folder. I opened the MANIFEST.MF file with the text editor. Then I closed it and made the folder to a jar file. When I double clicked the jar file, it says "corrupted jar file". I don't know why; is it because I opened the MANIFEST file with the text editor or why?

Comment: _Then I closed it and made the folder to a jar file._ How did you do this, with the `jar` command or something else? You can also try `jar tvf filename.jar` to see if it gives you any additional output or hints.

Comment: What text editor did you use? What changes did you make?

Answer (score 1):

In the future, you can use the `jar` command to remove files and add them back into a jar.

List all files in the jar:

```
jar tvf application.jar
```

Extract a file from the jar:

```
jar xvf application.jar path/of/file/to/extract
```

Add a file back into the jar:

```
jar uvf application.jar path/of/file/to/extract
```

MANIFEST files get a little special handling. If you want to add it back in:

```
jar uvfm application.jar mymanifest
```

*Note: In all the commands above the v flag is used to provide verbose feedback from the command and can be omitted if you want.*

Answer (score 0):

If I understood right, your new jar contains a redundant folder because you zipped the folder, but what you had to do is to zip only content of that folder.